# Group by similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL server 2012.

I am capturing the UserAgent into my database and I am trying to run some queries on it on it.

I want to lump 32 bit and 64 bit entries together Below is what these show up like in the db.

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0

my current query:

```
Select     count(*) as counts, UA
from        mytable
group by    UA
order by    counts desc
```

What would be a good way to do this? Can I do a sub-string on the last X chars? The query I have assumes these are different entries (which is what I would expect to happen)

Comment: Is `WOW64;` the only such change possible, or are there others of the same sort?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a reference table for the entries, with categorizations on what the values mean.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Most likely only WOW64 is to be added

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree and will probably implement in the future, anything you had for now?

Comment: Also, we have close to 200,000 unique useragents

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `WOW64;` is the only substring that's different between the 2 values, you could use a `REPLACE` on the string before grouping, like so:

```
Select     count(*) as counts, replace(UA,' WOW64;','')
from        mytable
group by    replace(UA,' WOW64;','')
order by    counts desc
```

However, as @GordonLinoff says in the comments, a better alternative would be to create a reference table, assign a value to all records that you consider to be similar, join it with your table, and group by the value column.